# Python add when entries have the same name

Tags: python, django, loops, django-models

I have a model with the registered sales of a publishing house.with the following code, I can get the name of the book and the quantity the client bought:

```
a=Sale.objects.all()
    for b in a:
        print(str(b.book) + ' ' + str(b.quantity))
```

So I get something like this:

```
Del mismo modo en el sentido contrario 15
Sobre el horror 1
Del mismo modo en el sentido contrario 5
Del mismo modo en el sentido contrario 2
Un lápiz labial para una momia 1
La cólera en los tiempos del amor 3
La cólera en los tiempos del amor 1
La cólera en los tiempos del amor 1
El tambor encantado 1
```

What I need now is a loop so every entry that has the same book name, sum or add that quantity number. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you share your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Django, to do this entirely in the database, it sounds like you want an [aggregation using `.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#values):

```
for book, total_sales in Sale.objects.values('book').annotate(total_sales=Sum('quantity')).values_list('book', 'total_sales'):
    print(book, total_sales)
```

The general case, if this wasn't only about Django, is to use a `collections.Counter`:

```
books_sold = collections.Counter()
for sale in Sale.objects.all():
    books_sold[str(sale.book)] += b.quantity
for book, quantity in books_sold.items():
    print(book, quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `book` is a `ForeignKey` to a `Book` model, it makes more sense to [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `Book`s instead:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

books = Book.objects.annotate(
    total_quantity=Sum('sale__quantity')
)

for book in books:
    print(f'{book} {book.total_quantity}')
```